# Crystal Reports Query Syntax Not Valid Server Syntax

Tags: postgresql, syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am attempting to reverse compile a crystal report and see how data is being pulled into the report.  The query in the crystal report SQL Expression Field is below

```
(
  select  coalesce(sum(ja.purchaseprice),0)
  from    saleslog ja 
  where   ja.saleid=masterlog.saleid and ja.empid=masterlog.empid    
)
```

Now as you can see that is not valid syntax for our postgresql server, if I copy/paste it directly in and attempt to run, it gives me the error of

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "masterlog"

How does this pull data into the Crystal Report but is not valid syntax?

Comment: have you checked the query generated by crystal reprots when this SQL expression is added?

Comment: @Siva - the syntax above is the query enerated from crystal reports.  If I directly copy/paste it into my server it does not execute, it throws the error above.

Comment: Yes first paste in crystal reports and then take query from crystal.repprts and check

Comment: That is my predicament.  This is the syntax shown by crystal reports.  I am wantin to reverse it and find the valid SQL Statement